# Pick the closest date/times without any overlapping and duplicates occurring

Tags: php, arrays, date

What I've got so far:

```
$dates[] = array("date" => "2016-02-18 02:00:00", "duration" => "600");
$dates[] = array("date" => "2016-02-18 02:05:00", "duration" => "300");
$dates[] = array("date" => "2016-02-18 02:10:00", "duration" => "600");
$dates[] = array("date" => "2016-02-18 02:25:00", "duration" => "300");
$dates[] = array("date" => "2016-02-18 02:30:00", "duration" => "600");

$pickedDates = [];

function findMeetingAlreadyExistsInArray($array, $dateTime){
    foreach($array as $item){
        if ($item["date"] === $dateTime) return true;
    }
}
function closestDate($dateArray, $compareDate, &$pickedDates = array()){
    $dates = [];  
    foreach($dateArray as $key => $originalDate){
        $date = $originalDate['date'];
        if(!findMeetingAlreadyExistsInArray($pickedDates, $date)){
            if(abs(strtotime($compareDate["date"]) - strtotime($date)) >= $compareDate["duration"]){
                $dates[$key] = abs(strtotime($compareDate["date"]) - strtotime($date));
            }
        }
    }
    asort($dates);
    $dateIndex = array_shift(array_keys($dates));
    array_push($pickedDates, $dateArray[$dateIndex]);
    return $dateArray[$dateIndex];
}
foreach($dates as $item) closestDate($dates, $item, $pickedDates);
print_r($pickedDates);
```

Result from above function:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2016-02-18 02:10:00
            [duration] => 600
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2016-02-18 02:00:00
            [duration] => 600
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2016-02-18 02:25:00
            [duration] => 300
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2016-02-18 02:30:00
            [duration] => 600
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2016-02-18 02:05:00
            [duration] => 300
        )

)
```

Expected Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2016-02-18 02:00:00
            [duration] => 600
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2016-02-18 02:10:00
            [duration] => 600
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2016-02-18 02:25:00
            [duration] => 300
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2016-02-18 02:30:00
            [duration] => 600
        )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my attempt... I changed quite a bit just to wrap my head around exactly what you are trying to do.

```
$dates[] = array("date" => "2016-02-18 02:00:00", "duration" => "600"); // 10 mins
$dates[] = array("date" => "2016-02-18 02:05:00", "duration" => "300"); // 5 mins
$dates[] = array("date" => "2016-02-18 02:10:00", "duration" => "600");
$dates[] = array("date" => "2016-02-18 02:25:00", "duration" => "300");
$dates[] = array("date" => "2016-02-18 02:30:00", "duration" => "600");

$pickedDates = [];

function dateExists(array $array, $date) {
    if (empty($array)) {
        return false;
    }

    $flag = false;
    foreach($array as $value) {
        // exact match
        if ($value['date'] == $date) {
            return true;
        }

        // range match
        $start = strtotime($value['date']);
        $end = $start + $value['duration'];
        $ts = strtotime($date);
        if ($ts > $start && $ts < $end) {
            $flag = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    return $flag;
}

foreach ($dates as $key => $date) {
    if (!dateExists($pickedDates, $date['date'])) {
        $pickedDates[$key] = $date;
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($pickedDates);
echo '</pre>';
```

This produces the desired results:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(19) "2016-02-18 02:00:00"
    ["duration"]=>
    string(3) "600"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(19) "2016-02-18 02:10:00"
    ["duration"]=>
    string(3) "600"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(19) "2016-02-18 02:25:00"
    ["duration"]=>
    string(3) "300"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(2) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(19) "2016-02-18 02:30:00"
    ["duration"]=>
    string(3) "600"
  }
}
```

Not sure if your `closestDate` function has to exist and with those exact parameters. Either way, you should be able to modify this to suit your requirements.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. You're a life saver! :)

Comment: Please check this https://3v4l.org/62dAS and look at the comment after "PLEASE CHECK THIS BIT" and tell me if that could be adapted into your function?

Comment: @ChrisBeckett it could be adapted with a bit of modification. it would be helpful to know how you're planning on using this.

Comment: Hey Mister Martin, sorry for the delay on getting back to you. Check the following link - https://3v4l.org/g3HEg  I've updated the example under "PLEASE CHECK THIS BIT" to try give you more of an idea of what information I want. It's going to be act like a recommendation for slot booking. There going to be a parent with multiple children and it's basically to get the best recommended times starting from which slot they want to book for their first child. That's why I've got the key as the starting time of the first slot.

Comment: As i'm looking for the smallest duration from the first slot to the last slot in the picked dates to be the smallest. So that the parent isn't going to be waiting around for long. However these times are just going to be recommendations, they won't have to accept the recommended times if they don't want.

Comment: @ChrisBeckett How are you planning to build the array? Should it be built from a specific date / something you will hard-code, or always from the first value of whatever is in `$dates`?

Comment: There will be array of meeting slots which will hold the dates. However there will be already one meeting loaded up just before this sorting. That will have a list of slots for that meeting and each of them slots will be a starting time because for each slot I want to know the suggested dates based on that slot being the start time. If you understand where I'm coming from?

Comment: Also in my latest link I've got meeting_ids and pupil, the pickedDates need to only allow one meeting slot per person. So a pupil could be in meeting_id == 1, 2 and 3. That pupil can only have one slot time in each of them meetings. However it should still work out the best meeting times even if it's checking between multiple meeting ids.

Comment: In your latest stab in the dark with that link. You've got the key working how I would like it to. It's just now working with the pupils and meeting ids

Comment: @ChrisBeckett I'm still not following, unfortunately... Maybe we could chat tomorrow about it, or you could post another question specific to this new case?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126194/discussion-between-chris-beckett-and-mister-martin).

Comment: Whenever you're free we can have a chat in the chat room in my previous comment.